# How to calculate data from a txt file (Python)?

Tags: python

I have a file with this datas:

```
internet|50.0
gas|85.0
food|235.0
```

I have to input some spendings and then tell how many times I used that spending.

Example: Internet 3 times, gas 2 times; 
and return te result = 320.0

I don't know how can I do this.

```
fileGastos1 = open("Expenses.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
lerFile = fileGastos1.read()
print("report spending")
while True:
    uGastos = input('Description: ')
    if uGastos not in lerFile:
        while True:
            print("Description unavailable, try again")
            uGastos = input("report spending: ")
            if uGastos in lerFile:
                break
    uQuant = input("amount: ")
    opc = input("Add more spendings [Y]/[N]").upper()
    if opc == 'N':
        break
```

Comment: Use context managers to handle files. Variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fileGastos1 = open("Expenses.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
lerFile = fileGastos1.read()
dataLines = lerFile.splitlines()
fileGastos1.close()

precio = []
categorio = []
indice = 0
totalPrecio = 0

for line in dataLines:
    splittedLine = line.split('|')
    categorio.append(splittedLine[0])
    precio.append(float(splittedLine[1]))

print("report spending")
while True:
    uGastos = input('Description: ')
    if uGastos not in categorio:
        while True:
            print("Description unavailable, try again")
            uGastos = input("report spending: ")
            if uGastos in categorio:
                break
    indice = categorio.index(uGastos)
    uQuant = input("amount: ")
    if not uQuant.isdigit():
        while True:
            print("please check your input, amount should be an integer")
            uQuant = input("amount: ")
            if uQuant.isdigit():
                break
    totalPrecio += (float(uQuant))*(precio[indice])
    opc = input("Add more spendings [Y]/[N]").upper()
    if opc == 'N':
        break

print("Precio total = "+str(totalPrecio))
```

Comment: You’re not closing the file. You read the entire file, then iterate over the lines a second time. You split each line twice.